# .NET application Kerberos, Sharepoint and Sql server authentication

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication, sharepoint, kerberos

In my C# web application hosted in IIS I want to connect to my database with a technical user without any credentials in my web.config (a user AD).
Moreover, my application communicate with a Sharepoint library with a kerberos authentication.

[schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbuzU.jpg)

My problem is I don't know how to do it.
Until now, the DB credentials were in the web.config and all worked perfectly but for more security I have to remove credentials from the web.config.

My IIS is configured with a technical user in the application pool, kerberos is correctly configured and the IIS authentication is configured like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efXug.jpg)

Could you please help me and say me if it's possible, if yes how to do that.

Thank's a lot

Comment: There's no such thing as `technical user`. Do you mean local account? Service account? The application pool's Windows account?

Comment: BTW in *most* cases there are no credentials stored in connection strings. The most common way is to use a domain account for the application pool, give database access to that account and use the `Integrated Security=True;` setting in the connection string

Comment: SharePoint also uses Windows accounts. The account will need permissions to the document library in order to read

Answer (score 0):

If you use Win Auth with impersonation in IIS to forward the Kerberos token to SharePoint your web process is impersonated.
Your only options are:

- use a sql login and encrypt the conneciton string in web.config
- use impersonation in C# and use cryptography and a secure Location for
  your AD tech. user password.